# Div elements overlap each other - css

Tags: css

Here's is the code http://jsfiddle.net/DTYEB/14/ , the images there overlap each other i want them beside each other. I can change the  position to relative in css class .container{} but functionality of the app changes **so is there any way to have spacing between the elements**

Comment: Can you post a more readable code (less whitspace)?

Comment: removed whitespace in css & code part - http://jsfiddle.net/DTYEB/19/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at developer tools, you will find that each div enclosing each images has position absolute with the same coordinates.

The issue is there:

```
    .container{
    position:absolute;
    width:64px;
    height:64px;
    top:200px; 
    left:300px;
    z-index:0;
}
```

Do this:

```
.container{
    width:64px;
    height:64px;
    z-index:0;
}
```

And create a parent div which has an absolute position.

This is one solution among a lot.

Comment: thanx for reply , but if i do that the drag functionality doesn't work in the required way :(    Note : The image elements can be dragged)

Comment: @user1184100 then create 2 classes .container 1 and .container2 and put the right coordinates to each of them?

Comment: correct that will solve the problem but there r diff functionalities in the code which i'll need to figure it out..thanx for the comments :)

Answer (score 1):

i have updated your script and add following code,

```
$(dragElement).css('position','relative');
$(dragElement).css('float','left');
$(dragElement).css('display','inline-table');
```

check now http://jsfiddle.net/DTYEB/32/

Comment: thanks hRaval.. but the images overlap each other before they are dragged i want it next to each other..